# LSTM validation

Tags: python, validation, time-series, keras, lstm

I have a dataset with 100k rows, which are the pairs of store-item numbers (eg. (store 1, item 190)), 300 columns, which are a series of dates (eg. 2017-01-01, 2017-01-02, 2017-01-03 ...). Values are the sales.

I tried to use LSTM keras to predict future sales, **how can I construct my train and validation dataset?**

I am thinking to split train and validation like `data[:, :n_days]` and `data[:, n_days:]`. So I will have same number of samples (100k) in both my train and validation dataset. Do I think it wrong?

If this is the way, how should I define `n_days`, should the train and validation dataset be exactly the same dimensions? (something like, n_days = 150, 149 days used to predict 1 day).

Answer (score 2):

> how can I construct my train and validation dataset?

Not sure if a rule of thumb, but a common approach is to **split your dataset into a ~80% training set and ~20% validation set**; in your case this would be approximately 80k and 20k. The actual percentages may vary, but that ratio is the one most sources recommend. Ideally you would also want to have a *test dataset*, one that you never used during training or validation, to evaluate the final performance of your models.

Now, regarding the *shape* of your data it is important to recall what the [keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) on Recurrent Layers says:

> Input shape
>
> 3D tensor with **shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim).**

Defining this shape would depend on the nature of your problem. You mention you want to predict sales, so this can be phrased as a *Regression Problem*. You also mention your data consists of 300 columns that make up your time series, and naturally you have the real sales value for each of those rows.

In this case, using a batch size of 1, your shape seems will be (1, 300, 1). Which means you are training on batches of 1 element (the most thorough Gradient update), where each has 300 time steps and 1 feature or dimension on each time step.

For splitting your data one option you can use that has helped me before is the `train_test_split` method from [Sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html), where you simply pass your data and labels and indicate the ratio you want:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
#Split your data to have 15% validation split
X, X_val, Y, Y_val = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.15)
```

Comment: thx for your reply. I have a problem here about the 80k and 20k training and validation dataset. Because each row is a unique store-item pair, our training data will only include 80k of the pairs, we haven't considered the relationship between store-pair and sales. For example, we only train on store 1, item 100 of the sale, but validation data includes store 50, item 100 sale, we never put them in the training before. Will this cause a problem? I am thinking if we do 80k and 20k split, we won't consider store and item pair as additional information. What do you think?

Comment: @Icy I see. That would depend on what you are trying to model. If you are trying to model your sales *per store* then you would have to train one model for each, and each with its own dataset. On the other hand, if you are trying to *model your sales on any store*, that is include the store name as a variable along with the other columns, then you will have to encode that categorical variable and add it to your input (check one-hot encoding for such)...

Comment: @Icy on that second case, *your dataset must have at least some examples for all the stores possible* for this approach to give good results, so it does not have a hard time extrapolating unknown values present on test and production data. Ideally if you had a balanced dataset (same number of samples per store) would de better, but NN can compensate for inbalanced data. I see your concern about splitting and it is comprehensible, but for those cases is the whole reason why we do cross-validation and kfold-validation (to prevent the split from affecting the training). Does this help you more?

Comment: yes, that helps. I wanna implement the second case to predict sales for all stores, as you said "on that second case, your dataset must have at least some examples for all the stores possible for this approach to give good results", since my rows are unique store-item pairs, columns are dates, to split my dataset, I probably should have the same rows for train and validation, and different time period of columns (say 2017-01-01 to 2017-03-01 for train, and 2017-04-01 to 2017-06-01 for validation? If so, is the time period of both be the same length, like 2 month for train and validation?) thx.

Comment: @Icy yeah something like that. Given you want a general model *regardless of your store*, and given you have sufficient data for all of your stores (and they are similar in performance), I think there will be no problem in ignoring from which store that sale came and just drop that variable from your model input. This applies as you don't want to predict based on *store* but rather by *product*, so you want your model to be able to predict your sales of that product without considering from which store it came.

Comment: @Icy another story would be if you now want to have a model per each store (case where your dataset per model will be exclusively from that store), or if you want to have a single model that includes store as a variable to consider (case where you will have to encode the store ID to your input as one-hot vectors, so you can compare predicted sales on a product across different stores). If you don't want to consider store as variable then my last comment would be the way to go. :) cheers

Comment: thx! that's clear. So if I add the one-hot vectors, is it right I just add another layer: "model.add(Dense(100, input_dim))" and merge with my LSTM model?

Comment: About the Input shape of LSTM, **3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim).** It also works when I do : model_lstm.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])), I think it means the batch_size is default set to 1?

Comment: @Icy I suggest you give a read to what one-hot vectors are. Basically you are modifying your input shape, and adding more elements to it. **Not necessarily do you have to add another layer for that.** Those things are not related. Layers are to increase your model's capacity, while here you are just including more variables to your input (*maybe* you will have to add layers, but only after testing and judging by yourself).

Comment: @Icy basically one-hot vectors are to prevent giving bias to your categorical variables. Say you have 3 categories: A, B and C. If you "encode" them as A:0, B:1, C:2 you will be having problems, as you are biasing your network (its activation function) to give more importance or weight to class C. Instead, one-hot vectors solve that by passing an array with zeros and a 1 corresponding to the class: A:[1,0,0], B:[0,1,0], C:[0,0,1]... this way you are not biasing your activations.

Comment: thx, I understand that. But stores are not sequential feature, my existing model is only LSTM() layer, that's why I am reluctant to just add the stores as variables into LSTM layer.

Comment: @Icy I see. I think that this is something you must try out, see your results and decide if it's worth it or not, as it is escaping the scope of this present question. Maybe you are right, and a good approach may be to have the store variable as another layer (non-LSTM) and then merge your results to predict sales (which inside the "black box" most probably will be equivalent for the NN to multiply by some factor that is intrinsic to each store). However it could also be the case that adding it to the LSTM will work ok, but the best is if you try :), my hunch is that there will be no problem.